# Is there a way to tell Maven in Eclipse where to deploy created .war or .jar files?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, wildfly, war

I am developing a webapp in Eclipse using maven-webapp archetype and I'm trying to deploy it on WildFly server. I managed to deploy it using Run As -> Run configurations -> creating new maven configuration and adding "wildfly:deploy" as a goal. This successfully creates a .war file inside target folder, but is its automatically deployed under /standalone/tmp folder on the WildFly server. Is this ok? Shouldn't the .war file be deployed under /standalone/deployments folder and be visible in the Servers tab in Eclipse? Because none of this is happening. 
So, I am wondering, how does Maven know where to deploy the files? It seems to me like I need to add some properties in my pom.xml file and point to the server path of deployment, but I can't figure out what.

Here is part of my pom.xml file:

```xml
<packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>websocket-servlet</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Every solution, comment or even an idea is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: In the Servers Section, right click the Server, than `Add and Remove` and than add your Project.

Comment: it is the same as Run As -> Run Configuration -> Maven configuration -> then set a goal to "wildfly:deploy" ? Shouldn't this action trigger an auto-deploy to WildFly?

Comment: With this eclipse will automatically deploy your project to the specific server whenever you start the server. After this, you can see the project under the server and publish(redeploy) it when the server is running.

Comment: Thanks. That is it. I have tried deploying just by doing Run on Server, the .war that it creates is not the right one, because it does not contain the compiled .class files. So it probably must be Maven build/deploy first, than Add on Server. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You need to remove the `sourceDirectory` and `resources` elements from your pom. Maven always does the right thing by default and your settings here will result in your source files being copied into the WEB-INF/classes directory of your WAR - which is pointless. Secondly you should remove the `javax.servlet` and `javax.websocket` dependencies because these duplicate APIs that are present in the `javaee-api` dependency. This latter dependency should also be scoped `provided`.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure about the `sourceDirectory` element and what exactly does it do, I was just following some tutorial. It works perfectly. I just have one more question - how do I know which dependency should be `compiled` and which `provided`?